# Xpages: get count of values in multi-value field in view

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have 100 documents with a multi-value field. The field holds 5 possible values (Albert,Ben,Chris,Don,Ed) let's say. The field must contain 1 value, but can contain up to 5.

I need to compute the number of docs that contain each value, so

```
Albert 56
Ben    22
Chris  79
```

etc.

This seemed easy. I constructed a view that contains the docs, the first column is the field, and I selected show multiple documents for multiple feeds.

In SSJS loop through my master list of values in the field, and for each one do a getDocumentByKey.

```
myArray = applicationScope.application;     
var dc:NotesDocumentCollection;

for (index = 0; index < myArray.length; ++index) {
      dc = view1.getAllDocumentsByKey(myArray[index]);  
   Print(dc.getCount())
}
```

This gets the first value correctly, but none after. If I just hard code a particular value, it works. But when I call the getAllDocumentsByKey a second time, it doesn't return the right value.

I think this would work fine in LS, but in SSJS I must clear or recycle or rest something, but I don't know what.

Comment: Maybe try either dc = null or dc.recycle() at the end of the for loop

Comment: Also, something doesn't look right about the first line. You are missing var, and you don't give it a type.  Are you sure that you actually getting an array?  Before your loop, add print(myArray.length) and make sure you have the correct length.  I suspect you will have "1", which explains why you only see the first value.

Comment: Making an answer out of my comments

Answer (score 0):

Bryan,

Two things to try in this order:

1. Your first line of `myArray = applicationScope.application;` doesn't look right. I suspect that you are not actually getting an array here.  I think you are just getting the first value from your applicationScope.  Add a print statement on the next line of `print(myArray.length);` If it is always equal to one, that is your problem. You are not using `var` and you should set the variable to some java type using a colon.
2. Before the end of your for loop, try setting your collection to null. `dc = null;` This way you know for sure that you are getting a new collection in the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Are any of your multi-value field values ambiguous? `getAllDocumentsByKey(Vector)` does partial matches. Unless you ever want that, I would recommend **always** using the second parameter and setting it to `true`, same always for `getAllEntriesByKey()`.

An alternative, which will definitely perform better, would be to add a total column to the view. There's a performance hit of that on the view indexing, but you can then use a `ViewNavigator` with `getColumnValues()` and `getNextSibling()`. `getCount()` is extremely poor performing in LS and will almost certainly be as poorly performing in SSJS/Java. See this blog post from a few years ago http://www.intec.co.uk/why-you-shouldnt-count-on-a-notesviewnavigator/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand that right: you want to count all values that are possible over an amount of documents to have a 5 value list with corresponsing 5 value counts, right?
You could loop through all docs, loop through all values and add entries to a HashMap with the value as key and an int as value (which should be increased everytime). Afterall you have a Map with 5 values holding the sums of each keys.

Answer (score 0):

You will never get the right answer with `getAllDocumentsByKey()`. When document shows in one category, it will be missing from the collection of next category. That's the way it works.

Use `ViewNavigator` instead. Build it by category and simply [count](http://www.mindoo.com/web/blog.nsf/dx/17.01.2013085308KLEB9S.htm) `ViewEntries`.