# Xpages: most efficient way to recalculate application scope variables

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have an app in which I need to display some counts, like ticket totals, number of tickets open/closed, number of tickets of type X,Y,Z.

Would like to use application.Scope to calculate and store these totals, but would like to update them when something changes (like new or changed doc).

How could I go about doing this?

Here is a link to a related question that I posted: [Xpages: get count of values in multi-value field in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701061/xpages-get-count-of-values-in-multi-value-field-in-view). Looks like this is exactly what I need. Some clarification, however.

The API has listeners to Database and Document. I am confused, wouldn't I want to use the Document Listener? I only want to capture changes to one type document.

I am not sure why I have to produce the functionality, so I must not be understanding something. Add two listeners like you have in your [post](http://www.intec.co.uk/openntf-domino-api-database-listeners/).

```
public List<EnumEvent> getEventTypes() {
    ArrayList<EnumEvent> eventList = new ArrayList<EnumEvent>();
    eventList.add(Events.AFTER_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
    eventList.add(Events.AFTER_UPDATE_DOCUMENT);
    return eventList;
}
```

Then I add this code:

```
public boolean eventHappened(IDominoEvent event) {
    try {
        if (event.getEvent().equals(Events.AFTER_CREATE_DOCUMENT)) {
            // Do something and return true if successful;
        }
        if (event.getEvent().equals(Events.AFTER_UPDATE_DOCUMENT)) {
            // Do something and return true if successful;
        }
        return false; // something went wrong, maybe an EnumEvent not implemented
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And in the //do something I call a method my Java Class (InitApp) called something computeTotals, and this method loads the applicationScope.whatever variables.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

OpenNTF Domino API has the concept of `DatabaseListeners` which can be assigned to a `Database` and hook into the `save()` and `createDocument()` methods. So, basically, when `createDocument()` or `save()` is called, it also runs custom code in the listener.

You'll need to basically reproduce that functionality. However, because `applicationScope` is only available from XPages code, it will only work from XPages code.

For backend code, you could update a "profile" document and, on each of your XPages pages, check if the last modified time for that document is later than the last time the `applicationScope` retrieved values from it. That way you could include backend creates / saves. However, you'll need to update everywhere that creates / saves relevant documents.

Comment: This is awesome, I have asked two clarification questions.

Comment: If you only want to capture one type of document, AFTER_CREATE_DOCUMENT won't be relevant. This triggers immediately after `Database.createDocument()`, at which time the Form field hasn't been set ;-) With AFTER_UPDATE_DOCUMENT (which triggers immediately after `save()`), the source (`event.getSource()` which may need casting to `org.openntf.domino.Document`) gets you access to the Document object, so you can check form name. So here just get ApplicationScope and increment the total.

Comment: `Events.AFTER_UPDATE_DOCUMENT` is a Document-level listener. But all listeners are added to the `Database` object. Then any document save for the database will trigger the AFTER_UPDATE_DOCUMENT listener. All you'll need to do is ensure all code to get your database goes through a single function where you also add the Listener. (If you're not already doing that, it may seem a lot of refactoring on first thought, but if it's the current NSF, it's always `getCurrentDatabase()`, so find and replace is quick - been there, done that! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for those who can't or don't want to use Java and OpenNTF Domino API:

1. Create your application scope variable in `beforePageLoad` event of application's welcome or home page or in a custom control which is included in every XPage.
   Create application scope variable only if it's null or empty = only one time across all users.
2. Change your application scope variable on control's `onchange` event

The following code is a working example for an application scope variable that contains a map of names with their number of occurrences
(corresponding to your former question [Xpages: get count of values in multi-value field in view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33701061/2065611)):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:
        if (!applicationScope.numbers) {
            var numbers = {};
            // populate numbers object
            numbers["Albert"] = 56;
            numbers["Ben"] = 22;
            numbers["Chris"] = 79;
            applicationScope.numbers = numbers;
        }
        viewScope.namesPrevious = [];
    }]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>
    <xp:checkBoxGroup
        id="checkBoxGroup1"
        value="#{viewScope.names}">
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Albert"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Ben"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Chris"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onchange"
            submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial"
            refreshId="inputTextarea1">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                for(var name in viewScope.names) {
                    if (viewScope.namesPrevious.indexOf(name) < 0) {
                        applicationScope.numbers[name]++;
                    }
                }
                for(var name in viewScope.namesPrevious) {
                    if (viewScope.names.indexOf(name) < 0) {
                        applicationScope.numbers[name]--;
                    }
                }
                viewScope.namesPrevious = viewScope.names;
            }]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:checkBoxGroup>
    <br />
    <xp:inputTextarea id="inputTextarea1">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            var list = "";
            for(var key in applicationScope.numbers){
                list += key + " = " + applicationScope.numbers[key] + "\n";
            }}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:inputTextarea>
    <xp:messages id="messages1" />
</xp:view>
```

Open the XPage in several browser tabs. You can see how numbers are "synchronized" between browser tabs. This works even between different browsers and users.